# Creating a search box using a text box with cue controls

Tags: c#, winforms, search, search-box

I'm working on a search box to implement in my project, I know that there is no such thing as a search box within the toolbox in VS.

But I came across a question in Microsoft forum, and one of their moderator provided a class (code) that can perform the same functionality as a window search box. This uses a text box with cue controls. But I'm having some problems implementing this, for instance I want to do a search on a listbox that contains a collection of string, what type of code can I implement that would allow me to narrow down the results display on the list box while I'm typing?

Below is a snippet of my code. Leave a comment if any clarification is needed.

```
private void cueTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cueTextBox1.Text == listBox1.Text)
    {
        listBox1.Text = cueTextBox1.Text;
    }
    else if(cueTextBox1.Text != listBox1.Text)
    {
        listBox1.Text = cueTextBox1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cueTextBox1.Text = listBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/2530848)

Comment: I already have that class, I just need to figure out how to narrow down the results display on the list box while I'm typing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695269/search-in-a-listbox). I think this question is similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  Once you have earned the requisite reputation, you can flag as duplicate and/or leave the link in comments.